# Why getElementById in that word? g is small and e and i word is capital?

Tags: javascript

doucument.getElementById("xyz").value;
this this statement why we write get in small and element word staring form capital word E same as B And I

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Camel Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) and it's just a styling/naming convention

Answer (score 1):

It's called lowerCamelCase. This is just writing style.

Answer (score 0):

Java naming convention dictates the following: "Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized." - from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

So in short, it's like that because convention dictates it should be.

Comment: Of course, JavaScript is not Java. (But did follow the same naming convention...) Then again, `getElementById` isn't defined by JavaScript, it's defined by the [DOM spec](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-nonelementparentnode-getelementbyid).

Answer (score 0):

Because as it called camelCase and it is one of the Javascript coding conventions, here's a list of other style Coding Conventions from w3school.
[js_conventions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)